# how to color column in Dired?

Tags: dired, colors

How can I manage with Emacs `dired-mode` colors?

For example, if I want to make column with file's last modified time and date to be red-colored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is typical in Emacs, you set `font-lock-keywords` in the particular mode, in this case `dired-mode`.

Library [**Dired+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) does this extensively for Dired mode. You can customize the faces that it provides, if you just want to change a color etc. from the default value.

If it does not already color things the way you want, then look at the [`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) code for setting `font-lock-keywords`, for inspiration.

Comment: Should I use `Dired+` instead of `Dired` for colorfill some columns?

Comment: You can, yes. It's easy enough to try (a single file). If it doesn't color exactly what you want you can at least look at how it does color things and do similarly to get what you want.